# HTML page center align in iphone

Tags: iphone, html, css

I am testing a HTML5 webpage in iphone. Also used CSS3. The page centered in all browsers. But problem is in iphone. It is left aligned here. I was trying -

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

But no luck. Please help me about this issue. The URL is:
http://www.stonegardenbd.co.cc/projects/vapp

Thanks.

Comment: I've found not using that meta tag altogether helps if you want a webpage to appear 'standard' on an iPhone. If you need it to zoom in, like in a responsive design, then include it. I only say this because I've had to go back and delete it from multiple sites to get them to look "right".

Comment: Why waste  space, centering the page. Leaving empty space to the left and right of the screen seems wasteful on a device that has limited screen-space to work with.

Comment: You should use CSS3 media queries to maximize control over your content on different viewport dimensions. My guess is it isn't centering because technically it is not responsive and the dimensions of the site don't fit the view port. You probably have something in your wrapper wider than 320px.

Comment: You need to mark the below answer as an answer if it answer your question.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the body min-width. I found that when the width was set, that it didn't center the body in the iOS browser.

Here is an example:

```
  body {
background-color:#0e7242;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size:15px;
min-width: 1000px;}

div.content {
    margin:0 auto;
    width:900px;
}
```

One thing to note is that if you have the meta viewport tag in there, the user will have to scroll out to see the entire webpage. You may prefer to have the entire width be loaded, and the user scroll in to see the text.